# Write all arraylist objects to text file

Tags: java, arraylist

I have this class currently, however when I try to write the data to the text file, it asks me which object I want to write. If I enter the instance name of the object, only the data stored in that object is printed. If I enter another instance name, the previous data is replaced with the new data.

```
public class WriteHotelData
{
public static void main ( String [] args) 
{
}

public void writeHotelData(ArrayList <Room> rooms)
{
    for (int i = 0; i > rooms.size(); i++) 
    {
        System.out.println( i + "Room information: " + rooms.get(i));
    }
}

void getRoomData(Room rooms) throws IOException
{
    Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(new       FileOutputStream("hotelData.txt"));
    try 
    {
      out.write
      (rooms.roomNumber 
      + " "
      + rooms.hasEnSuite 
      + " "
      + rooms.bookingName 
      + " "
      + rooms.bookingNights 
      + " "
      + rooms.isBooked);
    }
    finally 
    {
      out.close();
    }
}
}
```

What I want is when I run the Write Data class, all objects stored in an arraylist are printed on separate lines in a text file, thanks!

Comment: are you asking how to "wrap" `getRoomData` with some for loop?

Comment: I need all of the object data stored in an arraylist to be printed at once, rather than seperately